# Como adicionar uma div (completa) ao asp:Painel usando jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajaxtoolkit

Olá.

Eu tenho o seguinte cenário.

Eu quero usar o CollapsiblePanelExtender do AjaxControlToolkit para fazer um painel collapsed.

Porém, o conteúdo que esse painel irá exibir será dinâmico e estará dentro de uma div.

A minha div já existe e dentro dela existem vários controles e quero adicionar esta div inteira dentro do asp:Painel que será exibido pelo CollapsiblePanelExtender.

Se eu pudesse fazer isto via codebehind seria só usar o:

```
Painel.Controls.Add(div);
```

Porém quero adicionar esta div ao meu painel via jquery ou javascript.

Como posso fazer isso?

**HTML (Paineis para montar o Collapse)**

```
<asp:Panel ID="painelCollapsedCabecalho" runat="server" CssClass="cpHeader">
    <asp:Label ID="lblCabacalho" runat="server" Text="Click here" />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="painelCollapsedCorpo" runat="server" CssClass="cpBody"/>
<cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpeCollapsed" runat="server" TargetControlID="painelCollapsedCorpo"
                              CollapseControlID="painelCollapsedCabecalho" ExpandControlID="painelCollapsedCabecalho"
                              Collapsed="true" TextLabelID="lblCabacalho" CollapsedText="Click to Show Search..."
                              ExpandedText="Click to Hide Search..." CollapsedSize="0" BehaviorID="collapsibleBehavior" />
```

**Script (Esta é a forma como eu tencionava adicionar a div ao meu asp:Painel, porém não funciona.)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $("#painelCollapsedCorpo").append($("#divPesquisar"));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Podes colocar o teu HTML e explicar melhor o que dispara o jQuery? clic do utilizador ou via JS?

Comment: Sérgio, inseri o código solicitado.

Comment: Essa função ocorre no Load da página.

Comment: @Sergio a function 'pageLoad(sender, args)' é chamada pelo .NET framework ao carregar a página. Se eu não estiver falando besteira é como o '$(document).ready()' do jQuery ou o 'onload' do javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Existem 3 questões iniciais:

1. Note que para adicionar dentro do painel você deve usar `appendTo`, pois `append` adiciona depois do elemento e não dentro
2. Você aparentemente quer adicionar `#divPesquisar` dentro de `#painelCollapsedCorpo`
3. O `<asp:Panel ID="painelCollapsedCorpo" ...>` pode estar gerando um `name=""` ao invés de um "ID"

Então o seu código deve ser algo como:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    $("#divPesquisar").appendTo($("#painelCollapsedCorpo"));
}
```

Se estiver gerando o "name", use assim:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    $("#divPesquisar").appendTo($("[name=painelCollapsedCorpo]"));
}
```

Porém se este não for o problema, existem três possibilidades de problema:

1. A primeira é o nome de ID que você pode estar com problema no "caso sensitivo" ou o nome está diferente
   Você procura por `divPesquisar` mas é possível que o div gerado tenha a id assim `divpesquisar` (p minusculo).
2. O ID de `painelCollapsedCorpo` é "caso sensitivo" ou o nome está errado (mesmo caso do `divPesquisar`)
3. Outro possível problema é que `pageLoad` *não* esteja sendo disparado. Existe um método no próprio Jquery que você pode usar o `$.ready`:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#divPesquisar").appendTo($("#painelCollapsedCorpo"));
       //ou assim $("#divPesquisar").appendTo($("[name=painelCollapsedCorpo]"));
   });
   ```

Forma simplificada do `ready`:

```
$(function() {
    $("#divPesquisar").appendTo($("#painelCollapsedCorpo"));
    //ou assim $("#divPesquisar").appendTo($("[name=painelCollapsedCorpo]"));
});
```

Porém se este `divPesquisar` é gerado automaticamente por outro evento, talvez ela ainda não esteja disponível, neste caso você pode verificar modificações no DOM usando [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), algo como:

```
var isReady = 0;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function( mutations ) {
  mutations.forEach(function( mutation ) {
    var nn = mutation.addedNodes;
    if(nn !== null) {
        var nodes = $(nn);
        nodes.each(function() {
            if(this.id === "divPesquisar" || this.id === "painelCollapsedCorpo") {
                isReady++;
            }

            if(isReady > 1) {
                $("#divPesquisar").appendTo($("#painelCollapsedCorpo"));
                //ou assim $("#divPesquisar").appendTo($("[name=painelCollapsedCorpo]"));
                observer.disconnect();
            }
        });
    }
  });    
});

var config = { 
    attributes: true, 
    childList: true, 
    characterData: true 
};

observer.observe(document, config);
```

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento, primeiramente muito obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @LeonardoRibeirodeAguiar se a resposta lhe ajudou, por favor marque ela como "correta".

Comment: primeiramente muito obrigado pela resposta.

Eu testei as três alternativas que você propôs, $.ready, ready simplificado e o MutationObserver, mas infelizmente não funcionou, a minha div continua não aparecendo dentro do painel collapsed, ela continua aparecendo abaixo do meu painel collapsed.

A minha div esta escrita no meu HTLM, ela não é gerada por nenhum outro controle.

Comment: @LeonardoRibeirodeAguiar veja eu editei a resposta, teste por favor

Comment: Guilherme, infelizmnete não funcionou como appendTo. Eu notei que no caso do MutationObserver ele não esta "entrando" no mutations.forEach(function (mutation). Em que momento (evento) eu devo chamar este MutationObserver? No load da página mesmo?

Comment: `MutationObserver` nunca irá executar, pois é como está na resposta *"Porém se este divPesquisar é gerado automaticamente por outro evento"*, em outras palavras, você só deveria usa-lo acaso fosse dinâmico, mas como não é o caso o correto é usar o `ready`, faça um teste simple @LeonardoRibeirodeAguiar faça isto e me diga qual o valor que ele mostra: `$(function () { alert([$("#painelCollapsedCorpo").length, $("#divPesquisar").length]); });` e posta o resultado aqui.

Comment: Entendi a parte do `MutationObserver`. O resultado do teste foi `0,1`.

Comment: eu quero adicionar o `divPesquisar` dentro do `painelCollapsedCorpo`. Os nomes estão OK, acabei de verificar novamente no código. O `painelCollapsedCorpo` existe, veja o código `HTML` criando ele no post da minha pergunta. `<asp:Panel ID="painelCollapsedCorpo" runat="server" CssClass="cpBody"/>`

Comment: @LeonardoRibeirodeAguiar Sim eu vi que existe, mas deve ser na hora de gerar o HTML talvez o "ID" seja um "name", use o `Ctrl`+`U` e verifique o código fonte por favor.

Comment: No fonte o ID que aparece é o `painelCollapsedCorpo` mesmo. Se eu remover a tag `runat="server"` do meu `painelCollapsedCorpo` e fazer o teste `$(function () { alert([$("#painelCollapsedCorpo").length, $("#divPesquisar").length]); });` o resultado é 1,1. Porém neste caso não consigo usar o `painelCollapsedCorpo` junto com o `CollapsiblePanelExtender` do `AjaxControlToolkit` porque o `CollapsiblePanelExtender` exige que ele seja `runat="server"`.

Answer (score 0):

Não é exatamente uma solução para o problema, isso não consegui encontrar, mesmo com a ajuda dos colegas aqui do StackOverFlow.

O que eu fiz foi mudar de estratégia. Ao invés de usar o **CollapsiblePanelExtender** do **AjaxControlToolkit** eu usei o **[Accordion do jQuery UI]**[1](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

**Veja como ficou simples a solução:**

**Script**

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
            // faço algumas coisas aqui.
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAbrirBusca" Text="Click here to search" />   </h3>
        <div>
             // minha div com os meus controles
        </div>
   </div>
```

Sei que não é a resposta, mas espero que sirva de ajuda para quem estiver com o mesmo problema.